# Getting Element type prefix from xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am fairly new to parsing xsd files and currently I have to get the prefix of the element type as from the element below.

```
<xsd:element name="USAddress" 
             type="irs:USAddressType">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>
      <Description>United States Address</Description>
      <LineNumber>Line H(3)</LineNumber>
    </xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

I would like to see if I can get the value "irs" from the type = "irs:USAddressType" in the above element.

The code currently gets the namespace associated with this prefix.

XmlSchemaElement.QualifiedName.Namespace gives me the namespace associated with the prefix irs which has been defined at the top the xsd file like below

```
xmlns:irs="http://www.irs.gov/file"
```

It would be great if there were some way I could get this prefix "irs".

Answer (score 0):

here is what I use (sorry it is in java)

```
public static String findNSQualifier(Document dom){
    Element e = dom.getDocumentElement();
    String regex = "xmlns:([a-z]+)=\"" + XSD_NS + "\"";
    for(int i = 0; i < e.getAttributes().getLength(); i++){
        Node attr = e.getAttributes().item(i);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(attr.toString());
        if(m.find())
            return m.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply James. But i was able to figure out a way.